# Fedora28 - firewalld stopped working as it unable to communicate with ABRT daemon

Tags: fedora, firewalld, daemon, systemctl, journalctl

We are currently running a Fedora 28 server. Due to the server being restarting multiple times, FirewallD has stopped working. Based on the error messages presented when we run the command `systemctl status firewalld`, it appears as though the ABRT daemon has failed.

How am I able to resolve this problem?

```
[root@ashishnkbaba ~]# systemctl status firewalld
- firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-08-08 22:39:32 IST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 2597 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2597 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba python3[2597]: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/sbin/firewalld'
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba python3[2597]: can't communicate with ABRT daemon, is it running? [Errno 111] Connection refused
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba python3[2597]: error sending data to ABRT daemon: 
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 22:39:32 ashishnkbaba systemd[1]: Failed to start firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
[root@ashishnkbaba ~]# systemctl restart firewalld
Job for firewalld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status firewalld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Please update to a supported release. Fedora 28 is past end of life.

Comment: is there any alternative as i knew life is already expired @MichaelHampton

Comment: As @MichaelHampton advised, you need to upgrade to a supported release. Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Unless the system is completely offline it poses a security risk, and as such isn't supported here. You will need to research ways to upgrade the system.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response @ChristopherH i've added to the lastest one and issue got rectified.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running an outdated and unsupported version. Please update the OS version, which will resolve it.